# C# RestSharp - put entire XML string to the container

Tags: c#, restsharp

i have below code

```
var client = new RestClient($"{apiURL}?q={q}&s={s}");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

var response = client.Execute<CustomClass>(request);
```

and this is the custom class
and this is the CustomClass

```
public class CustomClass
{
            public string State { get; set; }
            public string Balance { get; set; }
            public string Detail { get; set; }
            public string GameResult{ get; set; }
}
```

everything is fine, except there is a issue, the output is something like this,

```
<UserBetItem>       
        <Detail>123</Detail>
        <GameResult>
            <BaccaratResult>
                <PlayerCard1>
                     <Suit>3</Suit>
                     <Rank>8</Rank>
                </PlayerCard1>          
                <ResultDetail>
                     <BRTie>false</BRTie>            
                </ResultDetail>
            </BaccaratResult>
        </GameResult>
        <Balance>104.25</Balance>
        <State>true</State>
</UserBetItem>
```

CustomClass has the properies correctly thus Detail, Balance and State can be plugged in correctly.

however, GameResult is dynamic for different game, thus the XML of this tag is always changing, I decided to store just the XML string instead of deserializing it.

but the result of GameResult became something like

```
"38false"
```

, which is the value string of the tags of the XML.

but I want to retrieve the entire xml string, i want the GameResult

```
"<BaccaratResult>
    <PlayerCard1>
        <Suit>3</Suit>
        <Rank>8</Rank>
    </PlayerCard1>          
    <ResultDetail>
        <BRTie>false</BRTie>            
    </ResultDetail>
</BaccaratResult>"
```

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Have you tried putting the xml in quotes \" <BaccaratResult> .. </BaccaratResult> "\"?

Comment: not sure your meaning